# How do I delete all the nodes in my custom linked list?

Tags: java

Is is possible for me to delete all nodes of my linkedlist to delete by my this code piece? If no then how is it possible to delete all the node at once!

my code is

```
EditNode mynode=start;
while(mynode!=null){
    mynode.editnext=null;
    mynode=mynode.editnext;
}
```

Help needed! Thanks in advance...

Comment: Set the head node to equal null, then let the gc do its thing.

Comment: If you've *really* got a linked list, you can just call `clear()`.

Comment: How should we know, you hide your implementation of `LinkedList` from us.

Comment: Use temporary space reservation for a node reference before you lost a node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code dosen't work because you are setting `mynode.editnext` to `null` and then trying to reference it.  So that's not going to work.

To delete all nodes in a linked list, in Java, just clear the head pointer.  Java will garbage collect the rest.

```
start = null;
```

Please note that this answer is meant for your custom linked list.  In production, you should use the Java implementation of `LinkedList`, which has a `.clear()` method on it.  This is a much cleaner way to handle a list.

This is because you may have stray pointers which point to an item in the list, and this will keep a reference around to the rest of the list and prevent garbage collection.  You shouldn't build organizational structure like the `editnext` property into the data structure.  They should be separate classes.

To clear all of your pointers in each node, use the following code:

```
EditNode mynode;
while (start != null){
    mynode = start.editnext;
    start.editnext = null;
    start = mynode;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the OPs code does almost work in an efficient way (but most likely not as intended). The only mistake is that `start` is not set to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#clear%28%29) method of LinkedList?

`public void clear()` - Removes all of the elements from this list. The list will be empty after this call returns.

Comment: I'm doing it without using java built in classes! so I need to do it manually like from my code? need help